# Python: Array out of bounds?

Tags: python, list

Effectively, whenever I use this code:

```
elif mSelect == 3:
score = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
scoreTwo = []
for x in range(0,6):
    file = open("./couple"+str(x+1)+"/tScore.txt","r")
    score[x].append(str(x+1))
    score[x].append(str(file.read()))
    scoreTwo.append(str(score[x+1]))
    print("Couple"+str(x)+": "+str(score[x])+" points.")
    file.close()
score = sorted(score)
```

I get an error stating that an array was out of bounds. I'm trying to write a piece of code that takes information from text files and ranks users based on the score saved there, but for starters being able to assign these variables properly would be nice...

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the entire error traceback

Comment: You are not using arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

`scoreTwo.append(str(score[x+1]))`

is producing the error for you. Your `score` array only has 6 subelement, i.e. indices 0-5. For the last iteration of you loop from 0-5, you are trying to access `5+1` index which is out of the bounds of `0-5` for `score`